# postmaster@servername.mydomain.com as "from" address

Tags: asp.net, email, iis, smtp

Very first time in 6 years, my client has reported that they are receiving email from my asp.net web applicaation with "from" id as "**postmaster@servername.mydomain.com**". Though, the mail id I use to send emails are "**support@mydomain.com**".

Not all the emails are delivered with postmaster@ as "from" address.

The "to" address of these kind of emails are like donotreply@ . So if a "to" address belongs to "donotreply" category, will SMTP will change the original "from" address to "postmaster@"?

We haven't faced this anytime before but why is it occurring now? I googled and found https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2030/should-i-set-up-standard-email-accounts-what-are-they and [Do I really need webmaster@domain.com, postmaster@domain.com, etc. emails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233624/do-i-really-need-webmasterdomain-com-postmasterdomain-com-etc-emails) but not sure what it has to do with my SMTP.

Can someone help me understand why it is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6bb0d71f-d3d7-4f59-aa01-4d5c022274a4.mspx?mfr=true

From the above link,

To rename the default domain

1.In IIS Manager, expand the SMTP virtual server, and then click Domains.

2.In the details pane, right-click a domain name, and then click Rename.

3.Type a new name for the default domain.

***For me the domain name was "servername.mydomain.com" and I modified it as "mydomain.com"***

Comment: I am having the same issue, but I did as you suggested, I renamed mine to `mydomain.co.uk` without the `postmaster` in front, but it isn't working :( I created [this thread](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/238578/emails-from-wordpress-end-up-in-junk) too.